# Cannot debug C code on vscode on macOS big Sur

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

Hi I have been trying to debug C code on macOS using vscode. I followed all the steps given here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac. but still when I start debugging a terminal windows appears but it shows this and gets stuck:

[image]

My tasks.json file on vscode:
[image]

My launch.json file on vscode:
[image]

Comment: Please put the output of a terminal as text not iumages so that we can read it.  Also have you installed Xcode and its command line tools - As it is C why not use Xcode for that, it is more integrated than VSC and does more

Comment: @jumpy123 what version of OSX - BigSur?  Also there's a problem no working directory (see the output of the launch)?

Comment: The error `working directory doesn't exist` seems to be caused by this folder on your Desktop with spaces in its name `sp_work/1.3 Linux - Socket in C/tcpServer`. Could you close VS Code, rename `1.3 Linux - Socket in C` to (for example) `1.3_Linux_-_Socket_in_C`, start VS Code, open the project and try again? And please, as mentioned by @mmmmmm, don't paste screenshots of a terminal, but the text within.

Comment: Also note t ha macos is b a sd on BSD and thus system calls differ from Linux. Don't use Linux tutorials on  macos as you will get interesting things to debug